# Bitmasking and Bitwise Operations in Golang

Tags: go, bitwise-operators, boolean-logic, bitmask

I'm a beginner to programming in general so i'm sorry if i make some mistakes while putting this question up.

The tutorial I'm following goes over this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const (
    isAdmin = 1 << iota
    isHeadquarters
    canSeeFinancials
    
    canSeeAfrica
    canSeeAsia
    canSeeEurope
    canSeeNorthAmerica
    canSeeSouthAmerica
)

func main() {
    var roles byte = isAdmin | canSeeFinancials | canSeeEurope
    fmt.Printf ("%b\n", roles)
    fmt.Printf ("Is Admin? %v\n", isAdmin & roles == isAdmin)
}
```

The guy in tutorial quickly mentions how this part is called **Bitmasking**.

```
fmt.Printf ("Is Admin? %v\n", isAdmin & roles == isAdmin)
```

Now, as far as i understand, the process that takes place here goes something like this:
The computer is being asked if both **isAdmin** and **roles** are equal to **isAdmin** and replies **true**.

But, when i'm trying to do this:

```
fmt.Printf ("Is Admin? %v\n", roles == isAdmin)
```

It results in **false**.

Can somebody go in greater detail on the whole logic behind this process? This bit leaves me a bit confused and i want to know why that happens. Thank you.

Comment: `&` is [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bitwise_operators), as opposed to `&&` which is the logical AND. What you're describing would be `isAdmin == isAdmin && roles == isAdmin` (which wouldn't make much sense). The linked wikipedia page goes into details about bit masking. Please read through it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All your role constants are special numbers where the binary (2's complement) representation contains exactly a single `1` bit, all other bits are zeros, and they are all different (the `1` bit is in a different position in each). This is achieved by shifting the `1` number to the left with increasing values (`iota`).

The `role` variable's value is constructed by using bitwise OR:

```
var roles byte = isAdmin | canSeeFinancials | canSeeEurope
```

Bitwise OR keeps `1` bits, and in the result there will only be `0` bits where each operand contains `0` in that position. Since all values being OR'ed contain a single `1` bit in different positions, `role` will contain as many bits as many different roles OR'ed, and at their special positions.

To easily understand the bits, let's print the binary representations:

```
fmt.Printf("isAdmin          %08b\n", isAdmin)
fmt.Printf("canSeeFinancials %08b\n", canSeeFinancials)
fmt.Printf("canSeeEurope     %08b\n", canSeeEurope)
fmt.Printf("-------------------------\n")
fmt.Printf("roles            %08b\n", roles)
```

This will output:

```
isAdmin          00000001
canSeeFinancials 00000100
canSeeEurope     00100000
-------------------------
roles            00100101
```

As you can see, `roles` contains `1`s where any of the above bit patterns has `1`.

When you use bitwise AND (masking), the result bit will be `0` if any of the input bit is `0` at a given position, and will be `1` only if both bits are `1`s.

The expression:

```
isAdmin & roles
```

Since `isAdmin` contains a single `1` bit, the above masking will be a number that may also contain a single `1` bit at most, only if `roles` has a `1` bit at that position. Effectively this masking tells if `roles` contains the `isAdmin` bit. If it contains it, the result will be a value equal to `isAdmin`. If not, the result will be a number consisting all `0` bits, that is: decimal `0`.

Visualizing the bits again:

```
fmt.Printf("roles            %08b\n", roles)
fmt.Printf("isAdmin          %08b\n", isAdmin)
fmt.Printf("-------------------------\n")
fmt.Printf("isAdmin & roles  %08b\n", isAdmin&roles)
```

Output:

```
roles            00100101
isAdmin          00000001
-------------------------
isAdmin & roles  00000001
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/OuyXJmP387H).

So the expression:

```
isAdmin & roles == isAdmin
```

Will be `true` if `roles` contains (includes) the `isAdmin` role, `false` otherwise.

Without masking:

```
roles == isAdmin
```

This will be `true` if `roles` equals to `isAdmin`, that is, if it only contains the `isAdmin` role and **nothing** else. If it contains other roles, it obviously won't be equal to `isAdmin`.